# Automatically straightening a Bezier Curve?

Tags: bezier-curves

Is there a command or function that will automatically straighten a bezier curve?

I'm using curves to give shape to arrayed objects, and I'd ideally like to start them all off as straight lines, but doing it manually is a chore.

Comment: flatten the vertices on Y, but yes there should be a Shift A > Curve > flat curve

Comment: @moonboots can't find 'flat curve' in 2.93 or 3.1.  is that from an addon, perhaps?

Comment: @Marty Fouts I meant it should exist but it doesn't from what I know   ;)  you need to go in Edit mode and flatten on Y with SY0

Comment: doh.  I missed 'should be'.  need more coffee.

Comment: or press V > Vector (or Automatic, depending on what you want to do next)

Comment: or V > Automatic.  I change vectors often enough that I use the menu short cuts VV and VA  also after VV or VA,  VL (for aligned) returns you to the vector mode you started in but doesn't change the handle orientations.

Comment: The fastest way I know of flatening a curve is to delete al the middle vertices and set the two ends to automatic.

Answer (score 1):

There is no command to do that as far as I know but, you can delete all the middle points if there are some and select the two ends of the curve, press <kbd>V</kbd> and click on `Automatic` :

[image]

After that you can set them back to `Align` if you want and the curve will keep its shape.